# Java HttpClient 4.4.1 can't create TrustStrategy for checking SSL Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I hit a problem on the newer version of HttpClient. The TrustStrategy seems can't be used anymore; however, I need to setup the method, isTrusted, on my TrustStrategy for initializing SSLSocketFactory. Does anybody have any alternative way to do that?

I have done a lot of research on it, and most cases are related to TrustManager. There are a lot of cases are related to ignore server's Certificate. It works on my local, but I want to check the Certificate is valid or not, so... I need to have TrustStrategy.

The following is my code for ignoring Certificate, and I want to add TrustStrategy inside of it.

```
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        }, new SecureRandom());

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

        BasicClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
```

I have tried another way to new SSLSocketFactory(trustStrategy, ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER), but it doesn't work. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the types of improvements that you'd like from others?

Comment: isn't it called TrustSelfSignedStrategy ? or was that removed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if TrustSelfSignedStrategy expects at least one cert in the chain. It seems to be godfather of QnD but for test it could be appropriate to override this method.